# How do i replace the null values in Item_Weight column with previous value? I have been trying with tmap but no success

Tags: talend

How do i replace the null values in Item_Weight column with previous value?

[image]

Comment: Is there one unique value for one unique identifier?

Comment: yes the unique identifier is Item_Identifier. The same can be seen in the Output link provided

Comment: Do you want to replace null with the first value for the item_identifier ? or always use the previous row's value?

Comment: Always the previous value. @IbrahimMezouar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tMemorizeRows` component in order to save the previous row's value, and then in a `tMap` check if the column is null; in which case you replace it with the previous row's value that was memorized with the `tMemorizeRows`. You must tell the component to memorize at least 2 rows (current and previous).
[image]

The syntax to access `tMemorizeRows'` saved values is `<columnName>_tMemorizeRows_1[n]` where n is 0 for the current row, 1 for the previous row, 2 for the row before that..etc.
You must also account for the case where the first row's value is null, and when there are multiple rows with null values

Comment: Thanks a lot. your a saviour

Comment: Hi. Can you help me again with the case where the first row's value is null?

Comment: What would you use if the first row's value is null ?

Comment: Hi. I am sorry but i am not able to understand the condition where First row values would be null. I tried a lot playing around with the component but no success. Please help me out it is a big request